# Creating table with Javascript and dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I am trying to make an application where you register a set of numbers, and then those numbers will be displayed in the table. I am able to register the first set of numbers, but if I change the numbers and press register again, i won't get a new row. Instead it updates the same row.

Basically I am trying to make this program work in the way that pressing the register button will create a new row.

```
window.onload = oppdater;



    function oppdater() {
        document.getElementById("btnRegistrer").onclick = registrer;
    }

    function registrer() {
        var arrayListe = [];
        var reg = {};

        var verdi0 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtUke").value);
        var verdi1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtAntmiddager").value);
        var verdi2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtBarn").value);
        var verdi3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtUngdom").value);
        var verdi4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtVoksne").value);

        arrayListe.push(verdi0);
        arrayListe.push(verdi1);
        arrayListe.push(verdi2);
        arrayListe.push(verdi3);
        arrayListe.push(verdi4);

        var tabell = document.getElementById("tblTabell");

        var rute = 0;
        var nyBestilling = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var rad = document.createElement("td");
            rad.id = "rute"+i;
            rute++;
            nyBestilling.appendChild(rad);
        }
        tabell.appendChild(nyBestilling);

        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            var inputt = document.getElementById("rute"+j);
            inputt.innerHTML = arrayListe[j];
        }

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bestillinger</h1>
    <p>Uke nr: <input type="text" id="txtUke"></input></p>
    <p>Antall middager: <input type="text" id="txtAntmiddager" max="3" min="2"></input></p>
    <p>Antall barn: <input type="text" id="txtBarn"></input></p>
    <p>Antall ungdom: <input type="text" id="txtUngdom"></input></p>
    <p>Antall voksne: <input type="text" id="txtVoksne"></input></p>
    <button id="btnRegistrer">Registrer</button>

    <table id="tblTabell">
        <tr><th>Uke</th><th>Ant. middager</th><th>Ant. barn</th><th>Ant. ungdom</th><th>Ant. voksne</th></tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Prefer `Number` to `parseInt`, `parseInt` will act very oddly to leading zeros (parsing them as octals). If you _must_ get "integer" values then prefer `Number.parseInt` and pass the radix argument: `Number.parseInt(string, 10)`.

Comment: You are duplicating ids. for every row. IDs are meant to be unique per page.
Avoid all the hassle and populate the td innerHTML before appending to the table instead of fetching them after adding.

Answer (score 0):

Element `id` values are [unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

You are creating elements with duplicate IDs in `rad.id = "rute"+i;`

Either don't assign IDs to elements or assign (preferred) and keep references to them if you want to manipulate them or keep `i` outside of the function and increment `i` to new values on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should work.

```
    var nyBestilling = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var rad = document.createElement("td");
        rad.innerHTML = arrayListe[i];
        nyBestilling.appendChild(rad);
    }
    tabell.appendChild(nyBestilling);
```

and remove the last for loop.

If you are styling based on the IDs, you could keep them, but better to change them to classes and update CSS definitions.